# Как правильно в коде описать отношения между картами в колоде?

Tags: ruby, логика

Предположим, что каждое достоинство игральной карты описывается отдельным классом:

```
class Jack {
    ...
}

class Queen {
    ...
}
```

Также есть отдельный класс колоды:

```
class Deck {
    ...
}
```

Интересует, как правильно описать взаимоотношения старшинств карт. Например, что в любой карточной игре (практически, но это неважно) Дама старше Валета, а двойка младше Короля. Также не стоит забывать, что в некоторых играх есть козырь, соответственно любая козырная карта будет старше любой не козырной.

Насколько я понимаю, это должно описываться в каждом классе (для каждого вида карты). Но как? И придется ли перечислять все карты, старше (и младше) которой является данная? И как это сделать, если я рассуждаю правильно, в языке Ruby? Или все-таки взаимоотношения должны описываться на уровне всей колоды?

Comment: В класс каждой карты добавь поле `force` (число) и `is_trump` (булев тип). И проверяй их по необходимости.

Comment: Карту характеризует **масть** и **достоинство**.

Comment: @D-side вот, точно :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы предложил унаследовать все типы карт от базового класса `Card`, в котором бы при помощи внутреннего массива, например, `TYPES` задал бы порядок следования "типов" карт. Индекс такого массива будет определять старшинство среди типов. В конструктор можно было бы передавать масть `suit` и признак, является ли карта козырем `trump`.

Чтобы объекты класса можно было сравнивать друг с другом мы при помощи `include` модуль `Comparable`, а потом переопределяем оператор <=>.

```
class Card
  include Comparable

  # Массив-константа типов карт в порядке убывания значения    
  TYPES = %w(Jocker Ace King Queen Jack Ten Nine Eight Seven Six).freeze

  # Конструктор принимает масть suit и признак является ли карта козырем trump
  def initialize(suit, trump = false)
    @suit = suit
    @trump = trump
  end

  # Вес мастей относительно друг друга
  def weight
    TYPES.find_index(self.class.name)
  end

  # Козырь или нет?
  def trump
    @trump
  end

  # Масть
  def suit
    @suit
  end

  # Переопределение оператора сравнения <=>
  def <=>(other)
    if other.trump == @trump
      other.weight <=> weight
    else
      (other.trump && !@trump) ? -1 : 1
    end
  end
end
```

После этого можно либо явно унаследовать классы карты от базового класса `Card`

```
class Jocker < Card
end

class Ace < Card
end

class King < Card
end

class Queen < Card
end

class Jack < Card
end

...

class Six < Card
end
```

Либо создать их средствами метапрограммирования (все-равно они однотипные). В цикле обходим наш массив карт `Card::TYPES` и динамически создаем одноименные классы, унаследованные от класса `Card`

```
Card::TYPES.each do |klass|
  Kernel.const_set(klass, Class.new(Card))
end
```

В результате объекты эти классов можно сравнивать друг с другом. С учетом козырной масти, чтобы пометить карту козырной, передаем true в качестве второго аргумента конструктора.

```
jack = Jack.new(:hearts)
ace = Ace.new(:clubs)

p ace < jack # false
p ace > jack # true
p ace == ace # true

jack = Jack.new(:hearts, true)
ace = Ace.new(:clubs)
trump = Ace.new(:clubs, true)

p ace < jack # true
p ace > jack # false
p ace == trump # false
```

В результате, какую бы колоду вы не сформировали затем в `Deck` ее всегда можно будет корректно отсортировать и сравнить каждую карту с другой, учитывая текущую козырную масть.

Comment: Столько нового для себя из кода почерпнул... Если бы вы добавили комментарии в код, то цены бы этому ответу не было.

Comment: @smellyshovel а какие участки вызывают затруднения? Что требуется прокомментировать? Если уточните сложные моменты, с удовольствием прокомментирую.

Comment: @smellyshovel прокомментировал, если что-то вызывает вопросы пишите - расширю ответ.

Comment: @Kromster, я так понимаю правило это не во всех играх работает, поэтому если честно я сам бы сделал блок в каком-нибудь из методов, в котором можно было бы переопределит это правило... Если кольцо нужно всегда, то вместо массива типа карт стал бы использовать двухсвязный список. Возможно мы еще увидим альтернативный ответ, задачка действительно очень интересная и не только в рамках Ruby.

Comment: @cheops я как увидел вопрос, сразу подумал, что он про кольца, ведь в остальном все тривиально.. А как перечитал внимательно, оказалось вопрос как раз про тривиальность...

Comment: @Kromster для кого-то тривиальность, для кого-то затруднительно. У каждого свой уровень. Для меня главная задача состояла в поиске best-practice по этому вопросу. Так-сяк я бы и сам описать мог, но хочется делать вещи красиво. Не думаю, что это зазорно.

Comment: @cheops спасибо за комментирование кода. Поскольку вопрос задал *я*, то решением будет ответ, который наиболее подойдет *мне*. Как только я убежусь в том, что мне все подходит, то сразу отмечу решением. Надеюсь на понимание.

Answer (score 7):

Не смотря на кажущуюся очевидность, считаю что наследование здесь ни к чему. Как минимум, получится много классов, каждый из которых надо не только определить, но и инициализировать. Конкретно для определения старшинства достаточно определить атрибут `seniority` (старшинство) и метод `can_hit?`. Этого будет достаточно и для определения старшинства, и для переопределения (тот самый пример, когда двойка может бить туза).

```
class Card
  attr_reader :name, :seniority, :hitable_seniorities

  def initialize(name, seniority, hitable_seniorities)
    @name = name
    @seniority = seniority
    @hitable_seniorities = hitable_seniorities
  end

  def can_hit?(other_card)
    hitable_seniorities.include?(other_card.seniority)
  end
end
```

Например вот так мы определим что двойка может бить туза:

```
Card.new("two", 2, [14])
```

Ну и осталось определить фабрику:

```
def build_deck(cards_params)
  cards_params.map { |card_params| Card.new(*card_params) }
end
```

Пример использования:

```
build_deck([
  ["three", 3, [2]],
  ["seven", 7, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
  ["ace", 14, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
])
```

Я умышленно не учитывал в примерах масти т.к. про них не было ничего в вопросе. Для использования мастей (особенно с учётом таких карт, как джокер), скорее всего, понадобится использовать композиции (см. [Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby](http://www.poodr.com/), главу `Combining Objects with Composition`). Но общее направление мыслей, надеюсь, понятно.

## UPD:

Сделал небольшой пример. Масти тоже различаются по старшинству, но для того, чтобы пример был более полным, сравниваются "традиционным" методом.

```
class Suit

  attr_reader :name, :seniority

  def intialize(name, seniority)
    @name = name
    @seniority = seniority
    @trump = false
  end

  def trump!
    @trump = true
  end

  def trump?
    @trump
  end

  def same?(other_suit)
    seniority == other_suit.seniority
  end

  def highter?(other_suit)
    return false if same?(other_suit)
    return true if trump?

    seniority > other_suit.seniority
  end
end

class Card
  attr_reader :name, :seniority, :hitable_seniorities, :suit

  def initialize(name, seniority, hitable_seniorities, suit)
    @name = name
    @seniority = seniority
    @hitable_seniorities = hitable_seniorities
    @suit = suit
  end

  def can_hit?(other_card)
    #hitable_seniorities.include?(other_card.seniority)
    return true if suit_highter?(other_card)
    return false unless same_suit?(other_card)

    seniority_highter?(other_card)
  end

  private

  def suit_highter?(other_card)
    suit.highter?(other_card.suit)
  end

  def same_suit?(other_card)
    suit.same?(other_card.suit)
  end

  def seniority_highter?(other_card)
    hitable_seniorities.include?(other_card.seniority)
  end
end

class Game
  attr_reader :suits_factory, :deck_factory
  attr_reader :suits, :deck

  def initialize(suits_factory, deck_factory)
    @suits_factory = suits_factory
    @deck_factory = deck_factory
  end

  def new_game!
    build_deck!
    choose_tramp!
  end

  private

  def build_deck!
    @suits = suits_factory.build
    @deck = deck_factory.build(suits)
  end

  def choose_tramp!
    @suits.example.trump!
  end
end

class SuitsFactory

  attr_reader :suits_data

  def initialize(suits_data)
    # возможные масти в игре
    @suits_data = suits_data
  end

  def build
    suits_data.map do |suit_data|
      Suit.new(*suit_data)
    end
  end

end

class DesckFactory

  attr_reader :cards_data

  def initialize(cards_data)
    # возможные в игре достоинства карт
    @cards_data = cards_data
  end

  def build(suits)
    suits.map { |suits| build_for_suit(suit) }.flatten
  end

  private

  def build_for_suit(suit)
    cards_data.map do |card_data|
      Suit.new(*card_data, suit)
    end
  end
end


suits_factory = SuitsFactory.new([
  ["Clubs", 1],
  ["Diamonds", 2],
  ["Hearts", 3],
  ["Diamonds", 4]
])

desk_factory = DesckFactory.new([
  ["three", 3, [2]],
  ["seven", 7, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
  ["ace", 14, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
])
```

Пример использования:

```
game = Game.new(suits_factory, desk_factory)
game.new_game!
```

Comment: Мне тоже показалось, что отдельный класс на каждое достоинство - это немного перебор. Один класс карты, конкретные карты - экземпляры, а их старшинство описывается внутренними свойствами. Так как-то логичней. Плюсую этот вариант.

Comment: А мне кажется, что создавать класс для каждой отдельной карты это правильно. Это было бы не правильно, если бы не существовало мастей, а всех карт было только по одному экземпляру. А поскольку Валет может быть как бубновый, так и трефовый, тоописывать старшинство надо как раз на уровне класса, а масть пускай будет просто его свойством.

Comment: И да, кстати, именно про последнюю упомянутую часть кода я и говорил "И придется ли перечислять все карты, старше (и младше) которой является данная?". Вы описали только 3 карты (достоинства). А мне по этому шаблону придется описать все. Не думаю, что это лучшее, что можно сделать (примерно так я бы и поступил сам, а я ищу лучшее решение. Собственно, поэтому вопрос и был задан).

Comment: Хотя с другой стороны можно описывать при помощи Range. Не придется столько писать. Советую внести соответствующую правку.

Comment: Фабрика, согласен, получается громоздкая. Но, вместе с тем, это гибче, чем инициализировать 52 объекта, каждый своего класса. В некоторых случаях, даже менее громоздко. Ну а сами данные легко можно вынести, например, в конфиг. Пример работы с мастями могу дописать, если нужно.

Comment: @anoam не 52 объекта, каждый своего класса, а 52 объекта всего лишь 14 классов. А вообще - надо смотреть по ситуации. Если, например, у какого-то определенного достоинства должны быть отдельные методы? (Да, я пока такого примера привести не могу. Но мало ли? Может игра карточная специфическая?)

Comment: @smellyshovel, 14 это тоже много для такой задачи. И их, всё равно, надо ещё и инициализировать. Да и чем они будут отличаться? Одной цифрой. Согласен: нужно исходить из задачи. Но, скорее всего, это тоже можно будет реализовать через композицию. Вообще, композиции предпочтительнее наследования согласно современным веяниям ОО-дизайна.

Comment: Я еще вопрос по поводу кода задать хочу. То, что вы называете "определить фабрику". Это значит что-то вроде "циклически инициализировать необходимые объекты класса"? Или как?

Comment: Фабрика - сущность, чьей единственной задачей является создавать другие сущности. В моём примере она собирает сразу коллекцию, но может создавать и отдельные объекты.

Answer (score 4):

Подозреваю, что отношения старшенства, можно описать некоторым свойством, value/weight, которое будет содержать число.

```
2 = 2
...
A = 14
// либо туз может быть младшим
```

Тогда все отношения между картами, можно будет описать в виде математических или логических выражений.

Если масть - козырь, то можно прибавлять некоторое значение ко всем картам одной масти.